# When i am trying to convert a base64 to image i am getting the following error Cannot resolve overloaded method 'write'

Tags: scala, base64

```scala
val decoder = new BASE64Decoder
val decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(base64String)
val uploadFile = "C:/Users/BabuSuku/Downloads/SpineorDownloads/test.png"
val image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes))
val f = new Nothing(uploadFile)
ImageIO.write(image, "png", uploadFile)
```

Comment: Please add the full error message to the question, it will give details of why the compiler can't find a suitable overload.

Comment: The problem might be in `new Nothing(uploadFile)`, it seems it should be `new File(uploadFile)`

Comment: If my or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If there's still anything unclear in my answer, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

you passed a string as third parameter to `write`. You need a `File`variable instead. Change the last two lines accordingly:

```scala
val decoder = new BASE64Decoder
val decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(base64String)
val uploadFile = "C:/Users/BabuSuku/Downloads/SpineorDownloads/test.png"
val image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes))
val f = new File(uploadFile)
ImageIO.write(image, "png", f)
```

see [Docs](http://otfried.org/scala/image.html)